# Nvidia cuda Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: nvidia, cuda, ffmpeg

I have installed cuda and cuda-toolkit-10.2 from Nvidia Cuda Toolkit [repository](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&target_distro=Ubuntu&target_version=1804&target_type=debnetwork) on my Ubuntu 20.04 machine to make a custom build of FFmpeg to using NVIDIA hardware acceleration so when I try to configure the source code with recomended command:

> ./configure --enable-cuda-sdk --enable-cuvid --enable-nvenc --enable-nonfree --enable-libnpp --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/cuda/include --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/cuda/lib64

I get this error:

```
ERROR: failed checking for nvcc.
```

and while I run this:

> nvcc -V

It's working fine.

Comment: Check the `config.log`, it will be more forthcoming.

Comment: thank you for your useful comment I fixed my issue by check the config log file.

Comment: @Amir You do not normally need cuda for NVidia hardware acceleration with FFmpeg, unless you have a special need?

Comment: @andrew.46 why?

Comment: @DaniilMashkin Most people are simply after simple hardware acceleration and if you compile FFmpeg against the nv-codec-headers you should be able to use your graphics card for this purpose. No need usually to install a big 'cuda' package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally, I downgrade my gcc and g++ to version 8 or lower, as though nvcc is not compatible with later than gcc version 8

Comment: You should be able to mark your answer as solved.